# Installing Google Plugin for Eclipse in Eclipse Android Developer Tools (ADT) Bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, google-plugin-eclipse

I've downloaded the Eclipse ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Now I want to add the Google Plugin for Eclipse. So I go to Help -> Install new
software... and enter the following:

```
gpe - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
```

I am presented with the following list, where I perform the following selection:

```
[ ] Developer Tools
[ ] Google App Engine Tools for Android (requires ADT)
[X] Google Plugin for Eclipse (required)
[ ] GWT Designer for GPE (recommended)
[ ] NDK Plugins
[ ] SDKs
```

but get the following install error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.2.v201303261859-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.2.v201303261859-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.2.2.v201303261859-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.2.2.v201303261859-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

My question is:

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. Why is the site asking me to install the [ ] Developer Tools
   when I already have ADT installed with Eclipse?

Thanks,

Jason Posit

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you running?

Comment: #2. The site is not asking you *to* install. It is asking *if you want to* install the Android Developer Tools. This is not a requirement.

Comment: I'm running Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 from the Android ADT Bundle. I was just wondering how come it is asking me to install ADT when I already have it installed as part of the bundle.

Comment: Wow you actually typed out the layout of that dialog box? Try imgur.com. Use Alt-Print Screen to capture, go to imgur.com, CTRL-V to paste, upload, then the bottom option link, Markdown, copy the link, enter `!` into your SO question and paste the link immediately after the exclamation mark. Voilá! Oh and the reason Eclipse asks for something that is already installed is because it is very flaky. That is why I'm here too.

Comment: Pinging this question. 1- In Jan 2014 there is the additional complication that Java 7 is required. 2- The ADT released as a standalone does not reveal which version of Eclipse it is built on, only its own version. 3- Is maintaining two versions of Eclipse, one for ADT and another for GWT, an omen for trouble?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this (again) and I fixed it by just checking "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"
* On Win7 Eclipse Juno SP1 4.2.1

Comment: This should resolve all the dependencies... @user2239505 : Your error indicates that you don't have some requirements (mylyn plug-in perhaps?) for the google plug-in to be installed.

Comment: I believe this worked for me. I am also Administrator which may also be required, but I'm not going to revert just to find out! Also see [Google FAQ](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#multiuser) which got me into this mess in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

(You've not specified what operating system you're running, so I'll explain what worked for me.)

I've solved similar plugin installation problems on Windows by simply running Eclipse as an Administrator.

Comment: That is strange, because eclipse installations are not made to be done system wide. Instead each user is expected to install their own eclipse in their home directory as a "local" package and then make their own customizations as please. Sources suggesting that users make global eclipse installations as administrator are simply wrong.

Comment: Ah I've made it a global install. I'm on a single user machine and didn't think twice about it.

Comment: This did not help. Am already administrator and had this error: `Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.4.1.v201309130745-rel-r42 `.